# C++ Class API method returning link to temporary iterable substance

Tags: c++, stl, shared-ptr

I'm writing simple class for undirected graph's representation. Within my class I use adjacency list for graph representation. I would like to add API method, which returns link to some iterable substance, containing vertexes, adjacent to given vertex.

I have the following idea about this method. First - create dynamically allocated `std::vector` and handle it with `shared_ptr`.  Second - fill vector with proper vertexes numbers and return the link to this vector. So it's prototype looks like:

```
const std::vector<int>& adjacent(int vertex);
```

Is it a good idea? Can I do better?

Regards,
Anton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea may work, but i strongly recommend you against it. It will be very error prone, and this function definition will look buggy to many other programmers who look at it.
I'd recommend you return vector by value, and do not think about this kind of optimizations until you come to the point where you really need them ( ie - your app is slow, and you are perfectly sure this is the bottleneck ).
If you want to avoid vector copying you can pass vector to this function by reference, so that it will be filled inside.